# Hilt Dagger Error java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class HomeFragmentViewModel

Tags: java, android, dagger-hilt

I was trying to inject my viewModel to fragment but I have this error :

java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.mas.cryptomasters.ui.fragment.home.HomeFragmentViewModel

My Code :

```
class HomeFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentHomeBinding>() {

    private val viewModel: HomeFragmentViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun init() {

        viewModel.homeMutable.observe(this) {
            when {
                it.reLogin -> requireActivity().reLogin()
                it.error.isNotEmpty() -> requireContext().crToast()
                it.data != null -> Log.e("TAG", "data != null")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this my ViewModel class

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeFragmentViewModel @Inject constructor(apiRepository: ApiRepository) :
    ViewModel() {
    val homeMutable: MutableLiveData<Response> = MutableLiveData()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            apiRepository.getHome()
                .let {
                    when (it.isRequestSuccess(it.body()!!.code)) {
                        RESPONSE.SUCCESS -> homeMutable.postValue(Response(it.body()!!))
                        RESPONSE.ERROR -> homeMutable.postValue(Response(error = "${it.errorBody()}"))
                        RESPONSE.AUT -> homeMutable.postValue(Response(reLogin = true))
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ensure your activity & fragment are having `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotation.
2. Add `implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.1"` to `build.gradle(:app)`

Comment: Thanks, bro, I already did that same time when I shared this Q, and it's working fine now, any way you deserve it :)